# Mongo: collection missing a property from instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, axios

So I have created a route handler for some surveys that are sent out to customers with an instance of the survey:

```
module.exports = app => {
  app.post('/api/surveys', requireLogin, requireCredits, async (req, res) => {
    const { title, subject, body, recipients } = req.body;

    const survey = new Survey({
      title,
      subject,
      body,
      recipients: recipients.split(',').map(email => ({ email: email.trim() })),
      _user: req.user.id,
      dateSent: Date.now()
    });

    // Great place to send an email!
    const mailer = new Mailer(survey, surveyTemplate(survey));
    try {
      await mailer.send();
      await survey.save();
      req.user.credits -= 1;
      const user = await req.user.save();
      res.send(user);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(422).send(err);
    }
  });
};
```

I only have the backend developed so I had to go into my React front end and add `axios` to my `window` object like so:

```
// Development only axios helpers - do not push to production!
import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;
```

And then create a survey object in console:

```
const survey = { title: 'my title', subject: 'Give Us Feedback' , recipients: 'renaissance.scholar2012@gmail.com', body: 'We would love to hear if you enjoyed our services' };
undefined

survey
{title: "my title", subject: "Give Us Feedback", recipients: "renaissance.scholar2012@gmail.com", body: "We would love to hear if you enjoyed our services"}

axios.post('/api/surveys', survey);
Promise {<pending>}
```

An email with a survey was successfully sent, but if you look at the `survey` instance and then look at the collection:

```
> db.surveys.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bc1579ec759e774e1bdf253"), "yes" : 0, "no" : 0, "title" : "my title", "subject" : "Give Us Feedback", "body" : "We would love to hear if you enjoyed our services", "recipients" : [ { "responded" : false, "_id" : ObjectId("5bc1579ec759e774e1bdf254"), "email" : "renaissance.scholar2012@gmail.com" } ], "_user" : ObjectId("5ad25c401dfbaee22188a93b"), "__v" : 0 }
>
```

The `dateSent` is missing:

```
          dateSent: Date.now()
```

I am running `mongod` locally and viewing this from `mongo` shell. If I had done this in MLab would the `dateSent` and `_user` have appeared? Is there a difference? Not sure why I am not getting those properties in the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your schema for the `Survey` have something like this for the `dateSent`:

```
var YourSchema = new Schema({
  dateSent: {
    type: Date
    default: Date.now
  }
}
```

This way you never have to set that date if you do not want to. In the example you gave there is no need to deal with that date at all.

[Should be just a default.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html)

Comment: Akrion, I read the documentation you provided and refactored as you suggested, but I still do not get a date when I look in my mongo shell with `db.surveys.find()`. I get the same as I posted above.